# Margin right is more in Safari on some machines

Tags: html, css, safari

On my Macbook and in Chrome and Firefox on my iMac everything is as it should be, but for some reason whatever I do the margin-right on my iMac in Safari is acting out.

I have tried to empty both server cache and browser cache. I've also tried to change the margin-right from the image to a placeholder around the image. Nothing helps.

Live URL: http://sebastiankolind.dk

Please take a look at the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when a child element exceeds the width of the container, different browsers have different strategies to "make it fit". In this case, Safari is shrinking the size of the `placeholder` divs.

In your file `pete-less-style.css`, after removing the style definition

```
ul.posts-list li article.has-thumb {
    width: 710px;
}
```

the page looks similar in all browsers.